# C# While -> For -> For loops to run multiple requests at the same time?

Tags: c#, loops

I'm currently trying call a function for each entry inside a `dataGridView` until a condition returns true, this would take long, since the **dataGridView** could have a total count of 100 entrys.

**Question:** Is there a way to call the function for the first 5 elements at the same time and then continue with the next 5 elements? This way those "100" entrys could be done faster. Or is there another way to do this?

**Current code Example:**

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(function)) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
}

private void function()
{
    bool loopRunStop = false;

    while (loopRunStop == false)
    {
        int count;

        for (count = 0; count < dataGridView1.RowCount; count++)
        {
            bool response = anotherFunction(string parameter1, string parameter2);

            if(response == true)
            {
                loopRunStop  = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read about parallel processing and [Parallel.ForEach Loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop)

Comment: You can apply TPL solutions, either Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach. Be aware that in CPU-bound operations (like this one) the actual performance improvement would be achieved only in multi-core CPU (you can set the max degree of parallelism to the number of cores).

Comment: Or PLINQ might be more convenient in this case.

Comment: I will read through all the named technices! I appreciate all the help, Thanks.

Comment: You can spawn separate threads to do the work. Parallel processing may actually be slower in this case.

Comment: I think this will just run forever if no solution is found and the code wont compile as well. Also this is not thread safe code you will get weird bugs once people start adding rows to the table.

Comment: Please note, that DataGridView can be accessed from UI thread only, so you might need to read out all data from DataGridView to arbitrary collection before you start processing data from multiple threads, or use something like [DataGridVew.Invoke(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to access DataGridViews's rows.